# Implement Night Mode on android app

Tags: android, configuration, themes

I want to add a night mode on my android app. For this case I added a folder `layout-night` in the `res` folder. Now I want that if my user choose the night mode theme from the settings, the app will use the layout from the layout-night folder.

Can anyone give me any suggestion how to implement it from the coding part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NightOwl has build its own implementation for separate night and day attributes. https://github.com/ashqal/NightOwl

Answer (score 2):

Use UI MODE Manager in android application to set night mode in application. for more details follow this link.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html

Comment: It's not set automatically? We have to set it manually? What if I want to provide resources based on it for the splash screen? This one is called before any code of the app...